# How do I fix empty 44px space in iOS7 view with ViewDeckController?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios7, viewdeck, iiviewdeckcontroller

I am in the process of transitioning an app to iOS7. All of the views throughout the app have a 44px empty space at the bottom that appears to be for a bottom toolbar or something, but I am not trying to display a bottom toolbar. This space also exists on views that do have a bottom toolbar and the toolbar just shows directly above it.

The red space shown is actually a view behind the black view. No matter what size I set the frame of the black view to, the red space is always shown. I am also hiding the status bar in plist, so don't know if this is an artifact from that or if it has something to do with navigation bar as they are both normally 44px in height.

I have looked at the transitioning guide and haven't found anything that's worked. Any ideas to what could be causing this and how to fix?

**UPDATE:**
I have tried setting edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeAll and extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars = YES (also tried NO) with no effect. When I look at the subviews of the navigation controller it shows a UIToolBar as hidden, but shows it contains a frame in the exact area the view refuses to resize to even with autolayout constraints.

**UPDATE 2:**
This is actually a problem with ViewDeckController (https://github.com/Inferis/ViewDeck) and the way it sets it's center view bounds.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I believe it has to do with the `UINavigationBar`. Try toggling the following options in Storyboard and see if it solves the problem. Namely, the 'Extend Edges' options:

[image]

These options can also be set in code with the `edgesForExtendedLayout` and `extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars` properties on UIViewController.

Comment: I have tried setting edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeAll and extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars = YES (also tried NO) with no effect. When I look at the subviews of the navigation controller it shows a UIToolBar as hidden, but shows it contains a frame in the exact area the view refuses to resize to.

Answer (score 1):

If you are transitioning to iOS 7, you should be using an Auto Layout constraint to anchor to the *Bottom Layout guide*. Control drag from your view to the *Bottom Layout guide* and choose Vertical Space from the popup menu.

Using frames in iOS 7 is harder and is the way of the past.

Auto Layout is hard to grasp at first, but it is very powerful once you get the feel.

Comment: Forgot to mention that I tried auto-layout as well and it did not work. It appears to be an issue with the navigation controller's toolbar. The toolbar is hidden, but the view is not resizing. It's like it thinks it's there when it isn't.

Answer (score 1):

This is actually a problem with third party library ViewDeckController (https://github.com/Inferis/ViewDeck) and the way it sets centerViewBounds for IIViewDeckControllerIntegrated. I was able to figure it out after changing to IIViewDeckControllerContained and seeing the view sized correctly.

In IIViewDeckController.m, just return self.referenceBounds for iOS7 like it does for IIViewDeckControllerContained.

Comment: You deserve more than one point for this answer, IMO. I had this issue with the status bar. I knew it had something to do with ViewDeckController, but couldn't pinpoint it. Thanks for the hours you probably saved me!